# change input text field into label with input typed value inside label javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text field into a label tag with input user typed text inside it. I have tried and seen many example which are working but not set value as a text in label. e.g.:

```
<input id="1" type="text" value="hi"/>
```

I want to replace this input text field with label or div tag with its `innerHTML` hi or the user typed value i have tried the example below but i it is not done by me.

```
<p id="1" onclick="wish(id)">sasdsad</p>
<script>    
    document.getElementById("1").outerHTML = document.getElementById("1").outerHTML.replace(/p/g,"div");
</scrip>
```

Comment: Sorry For Mistake document.getElementById("1").outerHTML = document.getElementById("1").outerHTML.replace(/p/g,"div");

Comment: i found this example in http://jsfiddle.net/s98J5/

Comment: ID's cannot and should not just be a number, they must start with some text identifier such as `<p id="sad1">sadsad</p>`

Comment: yes it is working for the above example but it doesnot work for problem thanks

Comment: do you want something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/xwszt2s9/

Comment: thanks the below answer and as well your comment helped me thanks rohit-kumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Element id should start with character not number.

With using jQuery

```
<input id="one" type="text" value="hi"/>

$('#one').replaceWith("<div>"+$('#one').val()+"</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use like this as well, just for an alternative solution :

**html**

```
<input id="toChange" type="text" value="hi"/>
<p id="clickMe" onclick="changeTag()">Click Me</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
function changeTag(){
  var originalForm = $('#toChange');
  var div = $('<div/>',{
               text : originalForm.val(),
               id : originalForm.attr('id')
            });
  $('#toChange').replaceWith(div);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ffuggauw/)**

Comment: The link of the demo is down